# how to Specify Search Criteria Code in an Anonymous Class?

Tags: java, lambda

One of the arguments of the following invocation of the method printMembers is an anonymous class that filters members that are eligible for Selective Service in the India: those who are male and between the ages of 18 and 25:

```
 printMembers(
 roster,
 new CheckMember() {
    public boolean test(Member p) {
        return p.getGender() == Member.Sex.MALE
            && p.getAge() >= 18
            && p.getAge() <= 25;
    }
        }
    );
```

This approach is not working .

Comment: What is the type of `p.getGender()`/`Member.Sex.MALE` ?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What's not working?  What's with the rest of your code?  Did you ever call CheckMember.test()?

Comment: why do you use "lambda" as a keyword when you actually use an anonymous class? And what is the question?